# Bigger product image on product page

Tags: magento2, css, frontend

I would like to make the product images bigger on the product page

I tried to increase these values in the following file:

> app/design/frontend/danisa/danisa_default/etc/view.xml

```
        <image id="product_page_main_image" type="image">
            <width>198</width>
            <height>198</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_page_main_image_default" type="image">
            <width>198</width>
            <height>198</height>
        </image>
```

But, It doesn't appear to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your block file :

```
protected $_filesystem ;
   protected $_imageFactory;
   public function __construct(            
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,         
        \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $imageFactory         
        ) {         
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;               
        $this->_imageFactory = $imageFactory;         
        }

    // pass imagename, width and height
    public function resize($image, $width = null, $height = null)
    {
        $absolutePath = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('custom_module/posts/').$image;

        $imageResized = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('resized/'.$width.'/').$image;         
        //create image factory...
        $imageResize = $this->_imageFactory->create();         
        $imageResize->open($absolutePath);
        $imageResize->constrainOnly(TRUE);         
        $imageResize->keepTransparency(TRUE);         
        $imageResize->keepFrame(FALSE);         
        $imageResize->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);         
        $imageResize->resize($width,$height);  
        //destination folder                
        $destination = $imageResized ;    
        //save image      
        $imageResize->save($destination);         

        $resizedURL = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'resized/'.$width.'/'.$image;
        return $resizedURL;
  }
```

Now Call inside phtml file :-

```
$block->resize('imag_file_name',500,400);
```

Comment: thanks but I am not sure where to find the bock file and phtml ?

Comment: Add code in your product page phtml file in your theme or you can execute this command : php bin/magento catalog:images:resize